# C++ adding chars to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

From my understanding a string is just an array of `char`, so if i have a pointer reference to some char values shouldn't I be able to do:

```
*dest = "char"
```

However that doesn't work i have to do:

```
        *dest = 'c';
        *dest = 'h';
        *dest = 'a';
        *dest = 'r';
```

Comment: What is `dest`? How is it defined? Also the second snippet is definitely not doing the same thing as the first

Comment: [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please...

Comment: A (`std::`)`string` is more than "just an array of `char`". No disrespect, but it feels like you are only trying to set up a pun here.

Comment: Note that `char *dest="foo";` is completely different from `char *dest; *dest="foo";`... The first is definition of pointer variable with initialization. The second is definition without initialization, followed by assignment to the single `char`, which the uninitialized pointer happens to point to.

Answer (score 3):

> so if i have a pointer reference to some char values shouldn't I be able to do:
>
> ```
> *dest = "char"
> ```

No, you shouldn't be able to do so.

`*dest` is a  `char`. A single `char` object can only hold a single `char` object. A string is an array of characters. You cannot assign a string to a `char`.

However, if you had a pointer reference to some **const** char values, then you could assign the pointer like this:

```
dest = "char"
```

This would make the referred pointer to point to the string literal. However, this is different from `*dest = 'c'; *dest = 'h'; ...`. The pointer assignment modifies the pointer and keeps the previously pointed characters unmodified, while assigning to the pointed character modifies the pointed characters, while keeping the pointer unmodified.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that by 'string' you ment a C-style string, so a `char*`

```
*dest = "char"
```

From what you said, dest is a `char&*`, when you dereference it, you get a `char`, type of `"char"` is `const char*`, so you're trying to assign a `const char*` to a `char`, which is a compile time error.

You should use `std::string`, which will enable you to do the assignment you described above, and also allocate and free memeory for you.

```
std::string dest = "char";
```